# Signum function and Fourier transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm extracting a portion of my notes which I believe I might have copied wrongly.

Given this equation:

$$\frac{G(\omega)}{2ic\omega} [e^{ic\omega t}-e^{-icwt}]$$

I want to find the Fouerir transform of the above. I believe it involves the Fourier transform of the signum function.
The Signum function is:

$$sgn(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 ,&x>0 \\ 
 0,&x=0 \\ 
-1, &x<0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
On my notes it says the Fourier transform of sgn(x) to be 
$$\frac{1}{\pi i\omega}$$ (is this the correct?)

Secondly, how do I apply the fourier transform to the above equation?

I'm pretty lost so any help would be good.

Comment: What is $G$? The formula works out to $G(\omega)\frac{\sin(c\omega t)}{c\omega}$, with no signum directly in sight.

Comment: G is the fourier transform of some g(x), both of which has not yet been defined.

Answer (score 3):

$$x(t) = sgn(t)$$

$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = 2\delta(t)$$

Now take fourier transform in both side

$$(j\omega)X(\omega) = 2$$

$$ X(\omega) = \frac{2}{j\omega}$$

$$sgn(t) \rightleftharpoons \frac{2}{j\omega}$$